# Creating UIButton (UIButtonTypeCustom) with an image at top & label at the bottom with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, uibutton, autolayout

I am trying to display Button with a text (single/multi line) at the bottom of it & image (has to look circular) at the top; the image & text must be highlighted on click. Like this:

[image: Desired Button with Images]

Here's the code in `viewDidLoad`:

```
btArtAndPainting = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btArtAndPainting.backgroundColor = [[UIColor cyanColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1.00f];

btArtAndPainting.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
self.vwContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[self.vwContainer addSubview:btArtAndPainting];

[btArtAndPainting setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:kIMGCategoryArtAndPaintingNormal] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btArtAndPainting setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:kIMGCategoryArtAndPaintingHighlighted] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

[btArtAndPainting setTitle:@"Art and Painting" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btArtAndPainting setTitle:@"Art and Painting" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

btArtAndPainting.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
btArtAndPainting.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.00f];
btArtAndPainting.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
btArtAndPainting.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
btArtAndPainting.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping | NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
btArtAndPainting.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
btArtAndPainting.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.00f, 8.00f, 20.00f, 8.00f);
btArtAndPainting.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(32.00f, 0.00f, 0.00f, 0.00f);

NSArray *constraintsWidth = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[btArtAndPainting(60)]|"
                                                                     options:0
                                                                     metrics:nil
                                                                       views:viewDictionary];

NSArray *constraintsHeight = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[searchBar]-10-[btArtAndPainting(60)]"
                                                                    options:0
                                                                    metrics:nil
                                                                      views:viewDictionary];

[self.vwContainer addConstraints:constraintsHeight];
[self.vwContainer addConstraints:constraintsWidth];

[btArtAndPainting layoutIfNeeded];
[btArtAndPainting needsUpdateConstraints];
```

Problem is that the text is not displayed at all (in both normal & highlighted states). See the linked images below.
How do I use UIEdgeInset to make room for the text? I also have tried creating a `UIButton` category but the effect is more or less the same.

[image: Normal Button]

Comment: If you modify a **UIButton** , I strongly advice you to creating **CustomView**

Comment: @grhnkdlk I think that won't be required. Could you please tell me what's the benefit of it in my use case?

Comment: In **UIButton** is hard to modifying, but customviews is much more flexible and free. For me your solution is *customview*

Answer (score 3):

Please use below code to set the inset,

```
CGFloat spacing = 1.0;
CGSize imageSize = btArtAndPainting.imageView.frame.size;
btArtAndPainting.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, - imageSize.width, - (imageSize.height + spacing), 0.0);
CGSize titleSize = btArtAndPainting.titleLabel.frame.size;
btArtAndPainting.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(- (titleSize.height + spacing), 0.0, 0.0, - titleSize.width);
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: No, it doesn't help. The image goes out of `UIButton` frame.

Comment: If image is going out of UIButton frame then there must be issue with image size. Try to use smaller image and observe the UI or try to increase the height of UIButton

Comment: Not quite sure about it. But solved the issue with using separate `UIButton` & `UILabel` wrapped in a `UIView`.

Comment: It works for me in override layoutSubviews from UIButton subclass !

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this situation so many times, that I decided to write a custom UIButton that supports flexible alignment in just few lines of code.

It's available here: https://github.com/namanhams/FlexibleAlignButton

Example:
`self.btn.alignment = kButtonAlignmentLabelBottom;
 self.btn.gap = 5; // vertical gap between image and text`

Comment: Greate! Does it also support AutoLayout?

Comment: @Smarto : there should be no issue. The internal implementation of the button is not affected whether you use AutoLayout or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to the problem. Created a UIButton subclass and override layoutSubviews()

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class ImageTopButton: UIButton
{
    override func layoutSubviews()
    {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let size = self.frame.size
        let imageSize = self.imageView!.intrinsicContentSize()
        let labelSize = self.titleLabel!.intrinsicContentSize()

        let totalHeight = imageSize.height + labelSize.height
        let heightDiff = size.height - totalHeight
        let padding = heightDiff / 2

        self.imageView!.center = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: imageSize.height / 2 + padding)
        self.titleLabel!.center = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: imageSize.height + padding + labelSize.height / 1.5)
    }
}
```